# Change product attribute select from dropdowns to buttons like in Madison Island demo store?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, rwd

New to Magento, apologies if this is a ridiculous question but can't find this anywhere. In the Madison Island demo store single product page the product attributes (size, color) are displayed as buttons.

[image: Product attributes selector as button]

In my RWD install the selectable attributes are displayed as dropdowns.

[image: Product attributes selector as dropdown]

What kind of voodoo do I need to make this happen? I have looked at the Switcher plugin (github.com/tzyganu/Switcher) but I don't think that is quite right. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "Swatches". You can find it under System/Configuration/Catalog/Configurable Swatches. I think that's what you're looking for.